# Accessing TortoiseSVN repository from Jenkins

Tags: python, svn, batch-file, jenkins

I'm trying to do a build for my project: here is the procedure:

I'm creating the job on Jenkins, then there is a batch script which triggers some local python scripts to start running, the python script then execute Tortoises command clinet to do check out from a repository. But the build fails, here is the error message:

svn: E120171: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'URLblablabla'
svn: E120171: Error running context: An error occurred during SSL communication

but when I open a browser and enter the URL it was fine, if I run the batch script from local CMD also no problem. It just cannot trigger the checkout from Jenkins. wondering what the problem is...

Comment: Jenkins already has infrastructure for checking out code from SVN one or more SVN URLs and polling them for changes. So the normal way of doing this should not involve TortoiseSVN.

Comment: thank you that's very helpful, I should tell my boss about that

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem on FreeBSD, I solved it this way :

```
sudo pkg remove subversion
sudo pkg install subversion16
```